# Confusion with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to wrap my tiny brain around how the `.htaccess` can convert my somewhat undesirable URL into a cleaner eye candy link.

This is my current, scruffy URL.

```
expand.php?category=Mods&subcategory=Wrestlers&faction=WWE
```

And what I would like it to be render as, would be something perhaps like this?

```
expand/Mods/Wrestlers/WWE/
```

Am I right in thinking this is correct syntax to perform this? Because it doesn't seem to do anything right now!

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ expand.php?p=$1&sp=$2 [L]
```

I would appreciate it if some bright chap might be able to help me out of this pickle!

Comment: Try `^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ expand.php?category=$1&subcategory=$2&faction=$3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this. You will need to make sure the rewrite matches the URL you wish to internally redirect too, which is `expand.php?category=Mods&subcategory=Wrestlers&faction=WWE`

So to take care of that you should be able to use this.

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^expand/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) expand.php?category=$1&subcategory=$2&faction=$3 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Hmm, that does look great! However when I place it on my htaccess it throws out the error 'The requested URL not found' Bizarre right? But when I place Jonathan De M.'s code in, it works except that it also changes my CSS/Images locations to the new url.

Comment: What is the URL you are putting in the browser? Just an example.

Comment: Realized I needed to run it from my sub folder, but that's nothing major. But yes sorry! This is the url I'm going with. http://localhost/WWFNoMercyMall/expand/Mods/Wrestlers/WWE/

Comment: So this htaccess file in the Mall directory?

Comment: Nope. It's in my root. I use WAMP for my localhost.

Comment: What is WWFNoMercy BTW? is that a directory?

Comment: Yeah it's a folder inside the www root one. Where all the website for expand is contained. To clear confusion, inside the WWFNoMercyMall folder is expand.php with sub folders /js/ & /images/ etc.

Comment: Ok create an `.htaccess` file in side that WWFNoMercyMall directory and use the code above. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: That did work! However my CSS and Imagery are screwed up. They are now linking towards http://localhost/WWFNoMercyMall/expand/Mods/Wrestlers/WWE/css/c.css However if I change my css include path to '/css/c.css' it looks for that css folder in my root, not the WWFNoMercyMall directory.

Comment: Oh sorry you kinda did. try this `href='/WWWFNoMercy/css/c.css'`

Comment: I seem to have fixed it! I was missing the folder name (assuming this was a fix) I believe?  <link href="/WWFNoMercyMall/css/c.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! You've been amazing, and apologies for my incompetence.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`^expand/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)?$ expand.php?category=$1&subcategory=$2&faction=$3`

Answer (score 0):

To internally rewrite `expand/Mods/Wrestlers/WWE/` to `expand.php?category=Mods&subcategory=Wrestlers&faction=WWE`, you'll need to make a regex that matches that first url. Your current regex would match an url with 2 parts, but your example url has 4 parts. I am pretty sure that doesn't fit ;-)

So... how do we fix it? Well, we make a regex with 4 parts. In fact, we know that the first part needs to be equal to `expand`, so we end up with this:

```
RewriteRule ^expand/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /expand.php?category=$1&subcategory=$2&faction=$3 [QSA,L]
```

If you add this to the `.htaccess` in your www-root and we now go to `http://example.com/expand/Mods/Wrestlers/WWE/`, we should see whatever expand.php outputs with those parameters.